# GMSPlacesClient autocompleteQuery with empty string

Tags: swift, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios, google-places

I am trying to make a fetch for places in a certain, small bounds that match a filter with no string search doing the following:

```
    let filter = GMSAutocompleteFilter()
    filter.type = .establishment
    let startCoord = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
    let upperCoord = startCoord.translate(using: -7, longitudinalMeters: 7)
    let lowerCoord = startCoord.translate(using: 7, longitudinalMeters: -7)
    let bounds = GMSCoordinateBounds(coordinate: upperCoord, coordinate: lowerCoord)

    GMSPlacesClient.shared().autocompleteQuery(
        "",
        bounds: bounds,
        filter: filter,
        callback: {
            (results, error) in
            if error != nil {
                self.proxyView!.errorLbl.displayMessage(FAUErrorLabel.MessageLevel.error, message: RQTText.errorsAPIFail)
            }
            else{
                print(results)
                print("done")
            }
        }
    )
```

However, if the string query is empty, the request fails. How can I search places with the ios SDK without a search string?

Comment: Has anyone had any luck with this?  I'm running into the same issue while trying to replace the deprecated picker.  I want to search for all establishments in a visible region, but am not finding an API that gives me this.  The above technique is the most promising so far, but I only get results if I specify a string to query on.  Just a region and a type isn't enough.